# How to configure spring-kafka's partition and replication in distributed environment?

Tags: configuration, replication, distributed, spring-kafka, partition

I want to configure 3 partitions and 3 replications of a topic in distributed environment with three nodes. How can I configure these by java api without shell command?

If I have three nodes: node1, node2 and node3. I want partition1 and replication3 are deployed in node1, partition2 and replication1 are deployed in node2, partition3 and replication2 are deployed in node3.

I've tried spring-kafka's api in single-machine environment, this can create a topic and 1 partition automatically. But it not work in distributed environment.

My maven configuration is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.1.x is no longer supported; you should be using at least 1.3.9.

1.3.x comes with `KafkaAdmin`, which can automatically configure any `NewTopic` beans in the application context.

See [Configuring Topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_configuring_topics).

> If you define a KafkaAdmin bean in your application context, it can automatically add topics to the broker. Simply add a NewTopic @Bean for each topic to the application context.

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(kafkaEmbedded().getBrokerAddresses()));
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic1() {
    return new NewTopic("foo", 10, (short) 2);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic2() {
    return new NewTopic("bar", 10, (short) 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried sping-kafka 1.3.9 and it was worked. But I have other questions. Spring-kafka api use BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS to set kafka info to zk, but the kafka I used is not support to create topics by `--bootstrap` param. By kafka shell command, I must use `--zookeeper` param to create topics. How did kafka api work.

Comment: They added `AdminClient` (which `KafkaAdmin` uses) to the Java `kafka-clients`. It does not talk to ZK, topics are configured via the broker. Even recent versions of the `kafka-topics` shell CLI have deprecated the zk connection `--zookeeper <String: hosts>              DEPRECATED, ...`.